# How to find the absolute coordinates of the kivy scatter image?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, scatter

[Kivy GUI window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHQie.jpg)
In the above GUI window I have a fish masked image and a fish tank which is the main background image. I want to extract the absolute lower left coordinate of the scatter to perform further cropping operation on the image and with the scatter mask. Scatter.bbox or scatter.pos is not returning absolute X,Y coordinates w.r.t image. When angle is less than 12deg it is working fine but as angle is increased new bbox rectangle translates more towards the bottom part of the window.

code for this:

```
`x = scatter.bbox[0][0]
 y = scatter.bbox[0][1]
```

#I have also tried - self.to_local(*self.scatter.pos)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For getting absolute coordinates use `to_parent` instead of `bbox`:

```py
scatter_name.to_parent(0,0)
```